# What can hit me during Smoke Screen?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have noticed that certain attacks can hit me during Smoke Screen. This goes especially for the lava of molten enemies.

I am not sure if the jumping attack of the Scavenger or the charging attack of the Thrall can be dodged by SS. Sometimes it does not seem to work, but that could be due to lag.

Now I wonder which attacks have a chance of hitting me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The molten attack is actually bugged when you use smoke screen.  If you 'die' while in SS in molten, your health will be at 0 but you will remain alive until your next hit and walk around with 0/xxxxx health.

SS is supposed to make you invulnerable for its duration but for some reason it does not take into account of molten.

The only other case I can think of where it doesn't save you is Diablo's bone wall, but you can easily spot that since it makes an inky dark patch on the ground before popping out.

Answer (score 1):

If you stand still enemy missiles could possibly hit you - same as casted spell: as molten, if you walk on it, it may deal damage. Smoke screen isn't an invulnerability skill, it is still a life saver: for example, pop it when you're about to get trapped by Diablo's bone cage.

Comment: This is incorrect; you will not be hit by missiles when smoke screen is active.

Comment: Actually ive been hit few times by missile while i was in Ss i guess it was a bug but ive noticed damage and there was no molten monster nor dot

Comment: This is incorrect answer. Smoke screen is indeed invulnerability skill. If you have been hit by missile, it due to lag. Also, I'm not 100% sure, but I believe SS can't help you against Diablo's prison (bone cage), as it's not direct damage attack.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing goes through Smoke Screen, however, most (all?) DoTs (damage over time) will bugged it.

Jumping attacks of Scavanger and Thrall's charge can be avoided by poping SS. In fact, only way to survive charge in Inferno in Act 4 (by corrupted angels) is to pop SS just before he hits you (well, unless you have out-geared it heavily).